# Understanding behaviour of simultaneous Animate with duration

Tags: swift, xcode, animation, uiviewanimation

I am having trouble understanding how simultaneous (animateWithDuration:animations:completion:) method calls interact with one an another in the case where both animate the same property of a given View.

I have created the following test project to illustrate the behaviour that I am seeing which is completely contrary to how I understand the documentation. Here it is:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  AnimationTest
//
//  Created by Jeremie Benhamron on 2017-03-03.
//  Copyright © 2017 beenie.inc. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Create and add a colored square
        let coloredSquare = UIView()

        // set background color to blue
        coloredSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        // set frame (position and size) of the square
        coloredSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: 50, height: 50)

        // finally, add the square to the screen
        self.view.addSubview(coloredSquare)
        //First Animation 
        // animate square moving to the right
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 4.0,delay: 0.0,options: [],animations: {
            coloredSquare.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 320-50, y: 120)
        },completion:{print($0)})
        UIView.commitAnimations()

        //second animation
        //animate square moving back to original position
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0,delay:0,options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.beginFromCurrentState] , animations: {
            coloredSquare.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 120)
        },completion:{print($0)})
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }

}
```

The following [youtube link](https://youtu.be/O43IQfBb6Kg) shows what happens in the simulator when I run this project.

Also the following is printed on the console:

true
true

I expected to see:

false
true

in the console because from my understanding, the second animation is supposed to interrupt the first animation which cause its completion block to be executed before the animation is completed cause its input parameter to be set to false.

Secondly I would expect the blue square to not move at all because the second animation should immediately interrupt the first animation before it can move the blue square. But instead I think were seeing some weird superposition of the two animations going on at the same time (because the blue square is not going as far as it would had I only included the first animation).

Also if you set the second animations duration equal to first (i.e. 4.0) the blue square doesn't move at all suggesting that their superposition somehow cancels out.

Whats also weird is that the beginFromCurresntState option seems to have no effect on the behaviour of the square.

Can someone please explain why animation 1 is not being interruped by animation 2?

Comment: A logical explanation could be this one: There's a queue for animations, if you play an animation and you also execute another thread under it, it puts the last animation thread in this list and waits until the first is finished. When it's finished removes the first thread from the queue and executes its completion handler. Once done that executes the next thread in the list. But I'm not sure about this behaviour.

Comment: The temporary solution I found for this is problem is to check  whether the  animation parameter has been changed since the animation was executed in the completion handler, to know whether or not a second conflicting animation was executed before the completion of the first animation.
The code in the completion handler in this case would look like:

`completion:{if(coloredSquare.frame.origin == CGPoint(x: 320 - 50, y: 120)){
                print($0)
            }}`

Answer (score 0):

The call to UIView.commitAnimations() should not be used here.

There are two alternative ways of defining an animation block. The older one uses UIView.beginAnimations() to start the block and then UIView.commitAnimations() to finish it. This is no longer recommended.

The current method is to use just
UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:) whereby the animations are automatically committed in the old sense.

However, this is not the cause of the weird behaviour which is absolutely reproducible with Xcode 9.1 and Swift 4...

The option .beginFromCurrentState is not being taken into account, it seems. I see no difference with this on to with it being off.

And instead of the first animation finishing before the second one takes effect, you are getting a mathematical addition of the two motions. The second animation is, in fact, being interpreted as 'move left' which becomes most obvious when you set the second duration to a smaller value than the first; the little square dashes off screen before slowly moving back in again. Fascinating!